# OpenVPN: can't access http/https via tunnel

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpn, openvpn, https, http

I have setup openvpn successfully on aws ec2 instance, I can connect using route53 private dns (ssh, ..etc) but I can't use private dns for http/https.

e.g: I have an instance that open up http on port 25000, its private dns named: test.abc.def
I can ssh to test.abc.def, I can use test.abc.def as name to connect to mongodb installed under it (for e.g) but I can't use test.abc.def:25000, even in "incognito" mode of browser, it shows "Your connection was interrupted"

I can use private ip address to access, e.g: 10.0.100.10:25000 but can't with dns test.abc.def:25000

so why I can ssh via private dns name but I can't http/https?

Comment: Your post is a little confusing. Are you saying from a remote machine you can use a domain name set up in a private R53 hosted zone for SSH, but you can't for http? Suggest you edit your question to clarify, and give us the big picture of what you're trying to do rather than "I tried this and it failed"

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you are trying access test.abc.def:25000/admin or GUI to set up the VPN.

What exactly happens when you try https in the browser? 
if its like "untrusted connection .. advanced"
then all you need to do is click accept the self signed certificate that openvpn created